# Is taking the mean of standard deviations of collections the same as the standard deviation of the union of the collections?

Tags: statistics

Given that I have 3 independent collections whose values were randomly selected from a given range, will the mean of the standard deviations of the three collections equal to the standard deviation of a collection that is the union of these three collection?

My research suggests this should be the case if the sum of the standard deviations of the three collections is divided by the square root of the number of collections, but I think I may be wrong, I can't seem to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groups $I=\{1,2,3\}$ and subsample lengths $N_1,N_2,N_3$ such that $N_1+N_2+N_3=N$. Each subsample standard deviation is
$$s_j=\sqrt{s_j^2}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{N_j-1}\sum_{k=1}^{N_j}(x_{j,k}-\bar{x}_j)^2}$$
Taking the mean of the subsample standard deviations:
$$m_s=\frac{s_1+s_2+s_3}{3}=\frac{\sqrt{s^2_1}+\sqrt{s^2_2}+\sqrt{s^2_3}}{3}$$
The union variance is
$$s^2=\frac{1}{N-1}\sum_{k=1}^N(x_k-\bar{x})^2=\frac{1}{N_1+N_2+N_3-1}\sum_{j=1}^3\sum_{k=1}^{N_j}(x_{j,k}-\frac{N_1\bar{x}_1+N_2\bar{x}_2+N_3\bar{x}_3}{N})^2$$
Since this is getting ugly, I assume $\bar{x}_1=\bar{x}_2=\bar{x}_3=0$ and $N_1=N_2=N_3=N_0$ so we get
$$s^2=\frac{N_0-1}{3N_0-1}(s_1^2+s_2^2+s_3^2)$$
and
$$s=\sqrt{\frac{N_0-1}{3N_0-1}}\sqrt{s_1^2+s_2^2+s_3^2}\leq \sqrt{\frac{N_0-1}{3N_0-1}}(\sqrt{s^2_1}+\sqrt{s^2_2}+\sqrt{s^2_3})$$
So in the end we get the inequality
$$\frac{s}{3}\leq \sqrt{\frac{N_0-1}{3N_0-1}}m_s$$